# Regex capture overlapping matches with a fixed point

Tags: regex, xml

So I require a regex which can collect the `Cid`, `id` and `visibility` attribute values from channels, where the `Cid` is shared by multiple, variable pairings of `id` and `visibility`. I can only seem to grab the first match (`0136, 10000, 21`) and not the second or any other proceeding match e.g. (`0136, 5000, 21`). Keep in mind the XML has multiple channels.

```
<channel Cid="0x0136">
   <type>A</type>
   <characteristics var1="0.1" var2="V" var3="3">
        <custom_range id="10000" visibility="21"></custom_range>
        <custom_range id="5000" visibility="21"></custom_range>
   </characteristics>    
   <visibility>0</visibility>
</channel>
```

My regex is:

```
/\bCid?\b="0x([0-9a-fA-F]+)"(?=(?!Cid)(?s).*id="([0-9]+)" visibility="([0-9]+)")/g
```

Comment: There was a closing tag </characteristics> too much. I edited and formatted the example. This is better no?

Answer (score 0):

A regex matches some text and if it succeeds tries again starting at the end of the last match.

So you will have your Cid match once and id & visibility capture a couple of times. Problem is that you can only access the last capture (.NET is an exception).

Maybe XPATH allows for a more robust or even more elegant solution but I never had to pick it up.

With a regex you can first use

```
Cid="(.*?)"(.*?)</channel>
```

Now the Cid is in group 1 and you apply another regex on group 2

```
id="(.*?)".*?visibility="(.*?)"
```

Id is in group 1 and visibility in group 2.

You can compose your triplets now with any imperative language using a few line of code inside 2 loops.

Comment: Thanks! I decided at this point to just use Java XML parser. Though I am glad to know the limit of regex in this regard.